# On FAQ Page in Magento my favicon icon is not shown

Tags: magento, favicon

Can you please help me. Only on one page my Favicon icon is not shown in IE.

https://www.unicycle.uk.com/faq/newbie.html

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the favicon element on the page. Probably a browser caching issue.

Comment: I have clear my browser cache. but it still not shown in  IE.